# How to handle Flutter FCM push notification when app in foreground for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using local notification when app in foreground, on iOS still cannot get notification when app in foreground but on Android it works perfectly.

The problem is how to handle push notification when app in foreground for iOS ?

This my AppDelegate.swift :

```
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {override func application(
      _ application: UIApplication,
      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {

      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
          options: authOptions,
          completionHandler: {_, _ in })
      } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
      }

      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

      FirebaseApp.configure()
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
      return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the `flutter_local_notifications` plugin for local notifications and `firebase_messaging` for push notifications. As of right now, these two plugins do not work together. This is documented in the readme of the first plugin, and the issue is being tracked on both plugins. You'll just have to wait for the pull request on `firebase_messaging` to be merged.

See [this issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1455) for more details.

Comment: I used flutter_local_notifications: ^1.1.5+1 and firebase_messaging: ^6.0.9